# hosting a JSON file for a 3rd party app/service to use

Tags: json, rest, azure, cors, getjson

We currently use Jive Cloud N which can use the Rest API and allows the use of Custom Apps.  Our UI devs have created an app which uses a JS `GET` to pull data from a JSON file for our "Birthdays and Anniversaries" tile.

At the moment, the JSON file is hosted on our UI dev's Google Cloud Apps account, but we wish to host it internally so we don't have to keep contacting them for changes.
I uploaded the file to our OneDrive for Business storage and created a public URL with full read permissions but the Jive platform is throwing an error trying to load the custom app.

The error is that the file

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
>   header is present

Our dev said that to get it working on his Google Cloud App storage, he had to specify the `allow-control-allow-origin` field in the server's **server app.yaml** file.   I don't know what this is and if there is an equivalent for ODfB/SharePoint.

To get to my question:  How can I host this JSON file on ODfB or even somewhere on our Azure tenancy so that it can be used?  Or am I better off trying to setup a Google Cloud App storage location and replicate our dev's setup?  FYI - I'd prefer the former because we're using M$ for a number of cloud hosted services already.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To get to my question: How can I host this JSON file on ODfB or even somewhere on our Azure tenancy so that it can be used?
>
> FYI - I'd prefer the former because we're using M$ for a number of cloud hosted services already.

Per my understanding, you could leverage [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) to store your JSON file, and you could use [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) to easily manage/share your files.

Moreover, You could manage anonymous read access to your containers and blobs, refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-manage-access-to-resources) for more details. Also, you could leverage SAS to grant limited access to your storage account for other clients, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1) for getting started with SAS.

For a simple way, you could create your storage account and leverage **Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer** to manage/share your file as follows:

- For cross domain accessing, you need to configure `CORS Setting`:

[image]

[image]

- For sharing your file(blob), you could **Set Container Public Access Level** or leverage SAS to grant limited access to your file for other clients as follows:

Right click your container, select "Set Public Access Level":

[image]

Sample file for share: https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/brucechen/index.json

Also, you could right click your JSON file, click "Get Shared Access Signature":

[image]

Sample file for share: https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/brucechen/index.json?st=2017-02-28T08%3A04%3A00Z&se=2017-09-01T08%3A04%3A00Z&sp=r&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=rVkorHeNOd4j2YhkmmxZ6DfXVLf1FoN2smY6mNRIoWs%3D